# What is a reasonable maintenance routine for a commuter bike?

Tags: maintenance, cleaning, tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much maintenance?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/how-much-maintenance)

I've purchased a nice hybrid (a Trek Fx) and plan on using it as my daily commuter, maybe averaging 50 miles per week on it.

What regular and preventative maintenance do I need to perform on the bike to keep it riding well?  Please provide a basic description as well as a rough schedule (e.g. "clean the chain monthly").

Comment: I asked that same question here, about a commuter bike ridden 40 km/day (100 miles/week): [commuter - How much maintenance?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2781)

Comment: Is there anything you need to know that's not addressed in the existing question? If there is, please add it to your question; if not, and you're covered, we can close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Neil, I'm reading over the others and think they're comprehensive enough for me (I'm a newb).  I'll ask more detailed/pointed questions if they arise.

Thanks guys

Comment: If you decide you have additional questions, you can either edit this one and we can re-open or you can just start a new question. Welcome to the site!