# What regular maintenance should be done to keep the bike in good condition?

Tags: maintenance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much maintenance?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/how-much-maintenance)

Everytime I get my biked serviced, it ends up costing me over one hundred pounds (including parts), which is not much less than what I originally paid for it (it's a second hand Marin Muirwoods).  However, everytime I get it back it feels radically transformed.

I accept that parts are going wear out and I will need to get it serviced from time to time, but I would like to increase the time between services, and keep the bike running well for longer.

All I have ever done myself is spray a little oil once in a while.  What basic steps can I learn to do myself in order to keep it in good condition?