# Which of these bikes is best for trails and bike paths?

Tags: mountain-bike, product-rec

I have a few options, please explain which one is better and why?

SCHWINN Searcher Comp http://www.mojekolo.cz/8413-schwinn-searcher-comp

GT Transeo 2.0 (2009) http://www.mojekolo.cz/11218-gt-transeo-2.0

Mongoose Crossway 450 http://www.mojekolo.cz/8371-mongoose-crossway-450

Thanks, I know nothing about the components and quality that comes with each bike.
I mainly want to use it for cycling around town and some off road on paths, no hardcore downhill or racing.

Comment: If it's for cycling around town, why did you use the "mountain-bike" label? What kind of surface is a "path"? Will you be, I don't know, jumping: leaving the ground?

Comment: No jumping, just trails and paths.

Comment: If you're not jumping I'm not sure whether you need/want a mountain-bike, then. There are problems with having suspension: a) cost (instead you can spend that money elsewhere, on a better frame, components, or accessories); b) weight; c) reliability; d) efficiency. For example I wanted a bike [just for commuting](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2767), on roads and bike paths; and the bike I got (and am happy with) doesn't have suspension. Can you describe or show a photo of what you mean by "trails and paths"? What's the surface: paved? dry earth? mud?

Comment: If you're in South Africa why are all your links to a Czechoslovakian shop?

Comment: Better is quite subjective, so we need to know more about what you want. Are you doing short rides or will this be your primary transport? From your question I suspect this will be your first bike and you're going to start riding. If so, any of these will be fine. But the front suspension is expensive and probably uneccessary - it's a marketing point rather than a useful extra.

Comment: @JL01 - I agree with ChrisW and moz, this question needs to be clarified or it risks being closed. Please consider updating the question with more details about the kind of riding you plan on doing, in particular with attention to what kind of surfaces you do most of your riding on. Other things you might consider: Do you need to fir racks or a basket? How long will you ride on your out of town rides? This will help us give you a better answer.

Comment: @moz, there is (unfortunately) no Czechoslovakia for 18 years already..... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissolution_of_Czechoslovakia

Comment: apparently there is still at least one .cz domain active though.

Comment: I like to ride on paths, too. But many of these are festooned with gnarly tree roots.  This is not a job for a street bike or hybrid, unless you love pinch-flats.

Comment: @Мסž - `.cz` domains are for Czech Republic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming these are the bikes (sorry, I can't read Czech).

http://www.bikepedia.com/quickbike/BikeSpecs.aspx?Year=2010&Brand=Schwinn&Model=Searcher+Comp&Type=bike

http://www.bikepedia.com/quickbike/BikeSpecs.aspx?Year=2010&Brand=GT&Model=Transeo+2.0+Disc&Type=bike

http://www.evanscycles.com/products/mongoose/crossway-450-disc-2010-hybrid-bike-ec020875

They all seem very similar - they're hybrid bikes with front suspension, aluminium frames and disk brakes built to a low price point. That and your comments make me believe that your "path" comment refers to sealed bike paths rather than mountain bike tracks. The GT has hydraulic brakes, the other two mechanical. On a cheap bike I favour mechanical brakes because hydraulic brakes are hard (expensive) to build well, and they're also expensive to maintain. But the GT is also 50% more expensive, so if you can get it for a similar price it is probably a bargain.

I suggest that the only way to pick one over the others is to test ride all three. If you can't do that it's guesswork - pick the colour you like or just buy the cheapest one.