# Want to start cycling, is this a good bike

Tags: shopping, beginner, advice

I have been riding on a cheap bike from Argos but I want to start doing it a bit more properly. Where I live, there are a fair few cycle paths, etc which aren't very flat. There's a lot of tree roots, pot holes etc.

Also, as I'm a bit of a novice, I can't ride on the road properly. So I want to be able to hop onto and off curbs.

My goal is to compete in a 100 mile race next year. I have been looking at bikes, what do you guys think of this one:

http://www.evanscycles.com/products/specialized/sirrus-2015-hybrid-bike-ec070673#select

Will this be a good bike to get?

Comment: This question was flagged for review as off-topic. It's not a bad question but "shopping" or product recommendation questions are generally a poor fit for a Q&A site like this because the answers frequently become out of date as manufacturers change their product lines. See [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). Better questions ask about general characteristics rather than specific models, like [this one](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/2767/213) that may apply to you.

Comment: Well it's like a chepaer version of what I now commute on, probably good round town, but it's not a 100mile race type of bike, and there's a significant discrepancy in the specs: the blurb says 24 speed, the details say 16speed, with a 50/34 chainset.  That's nice on the flat but not a chainset for steep hills.  Also if you can't ride properly, you won't want to be hopping on and off curbs, instead get the hang of the roads, including picking routes.