# Bicycle for commuting to office

Tags: commuting-bike

I am 6ft tall , 87 Kg Living in Kolkata .Which bicycle will suit for 10x2 KM to n fro to commute to my office?

Comment: This was my question on that subject for a `20km x 2` commute: [What bike+equipment for a long daily urban commute?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/2767/1097) -- "but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site".

Comment: @ChrisW yep - and this one will be closed too, as soon as 5 votes are in.  It'll be either "too broad" or "off topic - shopping/product rec"

Comment: Your height and weight are easily within limits, so for such a short commute, any decent-quality bike will do. Go with your preferences and your budget. Don't forget accessories like lights, helmet etc. But product recs are off-topic here.

Comment: And if this is your first bike, my usual brand recommendation is "Used".  You will learn better what bike is "ideal" for you after months/years of riding and will know more about selecting a bike.  No sense spending big bucks now.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following before deciding your bike

- regions humidity and weather
- Terrains
- Bicycle path/route quality
- City pollution level
- Bicycle facility
- changing room/shower/etc

If none of that above are under ideal conditions, you should consider an ebike , use good puncture proof tyres such as Schwalbe marathon/marathon plus. Get a suspension fork if required. For security , you need to find a solid pole/stand that you can put U-lock + chains instead of taking them home.

Comment: Thank you for keeping your answer generic, which keeps it relevant for years.

Comment: leaving lock behind it is a bad idea. What going to happen if someone steal them or sabotage them during the night ?

Comment: @kifli : Yes, in some country I know, people tend to sell meterial that cost 100  times of original values to scrap metal yard for a few penny. But first, you need a grinder to deal with a good U-lock.  Second, those lock and chains will weight 2kg to 5kg++ that you wouldn't want to bring everywhere.  
And lock are like tying up your shoes lace before running from the bear : you don't need to be fast, you just need to outrun the unprepared person next to you.

Comment: -.-" no you steal the lock in order to steal the bike. No lock = any safety measure on the bike.

Comment: @kifli : There is a reason that why heavy lock and chain permanent in an unattended place. While travel, you still bring a secondary lock with you.  I don't see a reason why the thief want to deal with a sturdy lock : a risk with bet of luck is not good for their business. :-D